# What is the best alternative to calling web services with an Android App

Tags: android, web-services

We can make Webservice call in android app by creating HttpURLConnection and POST request.
**Something like the following**

```
    httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
    httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "keep-alive");
    httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/xml");
    httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("SendChunked", "True");
    ....
    httpURLConnection.connect();
    OutputStream out = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
    out.write("request data in soap format");// send request
    InputStream response = httpURLConnection.getInputStream(); //receive response
```

Here I have to create SOAP like xml to send data and also receive data in that format.  Is there any better approach to call webservice?

**What is the best alternative to calling web services with an Android App**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use SOAP or REST approach for your webservice. 
 See the programs from

[REST and SOAP webservice in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6929180/rest-and-soap-webservice-in-android)

*** SOAP ***

Pros:

- Langauge, platform, and transport agnostic
- Designed to handle distributed computing environments
- Is the prevailing standard for web services, and hence has better support from other standards (WSDL, WS-*) and tooling from vendors
- Built-in error handling (faults)
- Extensibility

Cons:

- Conceptually more difficult, more "heavy-weight" than REST
- More verbose
- Harder to develop, requires tools

*** REST ***

Pros:

- Language and platform agnostic
- Much simpler to develop than SOAP
- Small learning curve, less reliance on tools
- Concise, no need for additional messaging layer
- Closer in design and philosophy to the Web

Cons:

- Assumes a point-to-point communication model--not usable for distributed computing environment where message may go through one or more intermediaries
- Lack of standards support for security, policy, reliable messaging, etc., so services that have more sophisticated requirements are harder to develop ("roll your own")
- Tied to the HTTP transport model