# Generating a web service client stub from WSDL for Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, web-services, wsdl

I'd like to generate a client stub from a WSDL url, and I've done it in Eclipse for a Java project, but I can't seem to do it for my Android project. Is there any way to do that, or do I have to use SOAP somehow?

Comment: It seems to require a different approach for Android development, like I said, I have done it, just not for Android.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14563306/using-web-services-in-android/14563386#14563386

Comment: This seems really cumbersome compared to the usual RMI used in web services, is there no similar way?