# How to parse wadl web service in android?

Tags: android, web-services, wadl

I an new to android and have not much knowledge on parsing so i came here for help.
I have a .wadl web service which is Restful api but i dnt know how to parse the web service in android.

I am attaching my web service code please help me on how to parse such a web service in android.

Thank you in advance

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://api.123paymix.com/gateway" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="unqualified" targetNamespace="http://api.123paymix.com/gateway">
<xs:simpleType name="SortType">
<xs:restriction base="xs:string">
<xs:enumeration value="ASC"/>
<xs:enumeration value="DESC"/>
  </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType name="PaymentStatus">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
    <xs:enumeration value="All"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="Pending"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="Posted"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="Settled"/>

</xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't much about how it works as never used it but may be https://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/ will help. Its an android soap library called ksoap

Answer (score 0):

Refer the below links.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14563386/1835764

I think it will give you some idea to parse the value to the webservice