# different between SOAP and restful parsing

Tags: android, rest

what is main different between Restful and Soap?

can any one explain restful with example ?

Thanks

Comment: ya but,what is the main different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. REST is an architectural style based on simple rules for how you use HTTP, SOAP is a much more complex and restrictive architecture with a huge set of (sometimes optional) rules capable of creating high level of security at the cost of complex programming. Any security in REST you will have to invent for your application.
2. True - RESTful services are intrinsically faster. Again, any multiple intermediate architecture you want in REST you will have to do yourself.

As per many many articles on the topic SOAP has its place and is unlikely to go away. IMHO most of what people think of as web services can be done better in a RESTful architecture.

Please Check below links for Restful webservice.

[Your Solution Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6978711/614807)

http://timewasted.net/?p=127

Answer (score 0):

Let's take a simple web service as an example: querying a phonebook application for the
details of a given user. All we have is the user's ID.

Using Web Services and SOAP, the request would look something like this:

```
Soap Request:


<?xml version="1.0"?> <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2001/12/soap-envelope"
soap:encodingStyle="http://www.w3.org/2001/12/soap-encoding">
<soap:body pb="http://www.acme.com/phonebook">
<pb:GetUserDetails>
<pb:UserID>12345</pb:UserID>
</pb:GetUserDetails>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

.

```
And with REST? 

The query will probably look like this:

http://www.acme.com/phonebook/UserDetails/12345
```

**If you want to use SOAP, you have to define first what is GetUserDetails and what it should do? But where as If you use REST, GET method is already defined in HTTP. just make use of it.**

Please correct if i am wrong..